# PrimeNg disable accordion expand button

Tags: angular, primeng

Is there a way to conditionally disable the expand button in PrimeNg accordion without disabling the whole header? I have some other buttons in the header and want them to be clickable, I only want to disable the expand button. I am displaying some items in each of accordion's body but if there is no item I want to disable to expand button. I failed to find an easy way to do that based off documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `disabled` input of the `p-accordionTab` component, like this:

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header I" [disabled]="items1.length === 0">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items1">{{item.caption}}</div>
    </p-accordionTab>

    <p-accordionTab header="Header II" [disabled]="items2.length === 0">
        <div *ngFor="let item of items2">{{item.caption}}</div>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I meant disabling only the expand button without disabling the header all together, I edited my question to make myself clearer, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue. @greenbanzai

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Here is my solution.

I created a signal to control the accordian status. The initial `false` value means that the accordion is not disabled.

```js
export class YourComponent {
    accordionTabDisabled = signal<boolean>(false);
}
```

Next, bind it to your `accordionTab` component. When handling the `onClick` event of the button, I set the signal to `true`. I emit an event later and set the signal to `false` when handling it so that the accordion is again enabled. In this case, I handle `onHide` event.

```html
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab [disabled]="accordionTabDisabled()">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <h1>Accordion Header</h1>
            <p-button (onClick)="accordionTabDisabled.set(true)"></p-button>
        </ng-template>
        <p-dialog header="My dialog" (onHide)="accordionTabDisabled.set(false)">
            Dialog content
        </p-dialog>
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```